# Insert if it doesn't exist, update based in ADDITIONAL condition [mongoDB]

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm creating a sync system in which I have the following type of data:

```
records = [
    {'_id': 0, 'name': 'John', 'sync_date': '2022-01-01 00:00:00'}, 
    {'_id': 1, 'name': 'Paul', 'sync_date': '2021-11-11 11:11:11'}, 
    {'_id': 2, 'name': 'Anna', 'sync_date': '2012-12-12 12:12:12'}
]
```

The idea is to (1) insert if there is no record with an `_id` 0 or 1 (the IDs of the records to insert/update) or update them ONLY IF the `sync_date` of the `records` is greater than the one in the collection. For example, if we have this in our collection:

```
[
    {'_id': 0, 'name': 'John', 'sync_date': '2000-01-01 00:00:00'}, 
    {'_id': 1, 'name': 'Paul', 'sync_date': '2023-01-01 23:23:23'}
]
```

Then it should (1) update John's instance, since the collection's `sync_date` is lower (older in time) than the one in our records, and *ignore* Paul's record because the `sync_date` available in the collection's instance is greater (earlier in time) than the one in our records. Additionally, it should insert Anna's instance as it's simply not in the collection.

The problem I see is that with `replace_one` and `update_one` methods if you add `upsert=True` then it will insert it not only when it's not in the collection but also when the `sync_date` is greater than the records' one. See:

```
for record in records:
    collection.replace_one({
            '_id': record['_id'], 
            'sync_date': {'$lt': record['sync_date']}
            },
        {'upsert': True})
```

I know there must be a more efficient way using an aggregate query, but currently this is my provisional solution:

```
for record in records:
    if not collection.find_one({'_id': record['_id']}):
        collection.insert_one(record)
    else:
        collection.update_one(
            {'_id': record['_id'], 'sync_date': {'$lt': record['sync_date']}},
            record)
```

Any ideas as to how to build the query?

Comment: One option is to use [`bulkWrite()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in one query, one option is to use aggregation with `$merge`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: {$in: recordIds}}},
  {$group: {_id: null, docs: {$push: "$$ROOT"}}},
  {$addFields: {records: records}}, 
  {$unwind: "$records"},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      record: "$records",
      docs: {$filter: {
          input: "$docs",
          cond: {$and: [
              {$eq: ["$$this._id", "$records._id"]},
              {$gt: ["$$this.sync_date", "$records.sync_date"]}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: ["$record", {$first: "$docs"}]}}},
  {$merge: {into: "collection"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m-ETawr2zik)